# Retrieving Y,U,V values from v4l2 capture in c

Tags: c, v4l2

Pardon my problem, this is my first. I was trying to experiment with getting the Y,U and V values from a YUYV picture directly from the webcam using the v4l2 C api.

So far capturing then writing directly to a file and opening it works . This is the snippet I used to get those values.

```
int Y, U,V, byte;
for (byte = 0; byte < buf.bytesused; byte +=3) { 
   Y += buffers[byte+1];
   U += buffers[byte];
   Y += buffers[byte+3];
   V += buffers[byte+2];
}
Y = Y/(buf.bytesused/2);
U = U/(buf.bytesused/4);
V = V/(buf.bytesused/4);
```

It does work but it returns almost the same values even if I change the location of the camera.

The `buf` is a structure as followed: `struct v4l2_buffer buf = {0}`, and  `buffers` is the one having the image.

Comment: Why the stepping by 3? (Thus you are reading the same value twice.) And is your intention to get the average of an entire captured frame? (In which case it's *fairly* possible the values are close together for different images - try with holding your hand in front of the camera.)

Comment: To @Jongware, Sorry, I named the`bit` variable wrong it should be `byte` and its stepping is three because the yuyv format stores two pixels in 4 bytes. Also my intention is to get the average values for that frame. Lastly, I have re-run the program with my hand in front of the camera and it did not change much, except for the U value.